# Perl DateTime duration format not displaying years

Tags: perl, datetime, difference

I'm having troubles with the difference calculation between two dates.

```
my $todayDate = DateTime->now;
my @updateDateFields = split /\//, $proteinObj->{lastUpdate}; #yyyy/mm/dd

my $updateDateTime = DateTime->new(
    year => @updateDateFields[0],
    month=> @updateDateFields[1],
    day=> @updateDateFields[2]
);

my $daysSinceLastUpdate = $todayDate - $updateDateTime;

my $dfd = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(pattern => '%Y years, %m months, %e days');
print "Last update was: ". $dfd->format_duration($daysSinceLastUpdate). " ago.\n";
```

And the output is this:

> Last update date:     2015/01/13 Last update was: 0 years, 22 months, 0
>   days ago.

It does't display 1 years, 10 months, 0 days ago.

Comment: BTW, `use warnings` tells me `Scalar value @updateDateFields[0] better written as $updateDateFields[0]` etc.

Comment: Wow, you're right, but it loads my app so fast i couldnt catch it, thanks a lot for the feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the `normalise` option in the `DateTime::Format::Duration` object, like this

```
my $dfd = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
    pattern   => '%Y years, %m months, %e days',
    normalise => 1,
);
```